# Google analytics web app

Tags: php, oauth, google-analytics

I've developed a google analytics joomla extension which a web site admin can include into it's joomla based web site to show analytics statistics to it's visitors. The workflow of the app till now is as follows:

1. User installs extension
2. Imports his google analytics profiles by providing username and password
3. Accounts and username and password are stored in the extension
4. Data will be fetched based on imported profiles and authentication is done via previous entered username and password

I've used this PHP script till now to get the accounts and statistic data http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

Since google released v3 of their analytics api everything is different especially in terms of authentication. The user needs to use the api console to get get id's and secret's. The problem is now when the data should be displayed on the fronend of the site to an anonymous visitor.
Can somebody tell me how this is doeable with the v3 api of google. I really hope I'm missing something.

Comment: You have forgotten to share the code you have so far. Please link your github repro or similar.

Comment: Added the google code link with the script I'm using..

Comment: $ga = new gapi($username,$password);
return $ga->requestAccountData(1, 1000);
Do you need more? The whole project is at http://g4j.laoneo.net/extensions/ganalytics.html

Comment: No, so what is the concrete problem with the anonymous visitor? Can't you pass the credentials server-side and only transfer the obtained data to client side?

Comment: Since version 3 google doesn't support credential based login anymore only OAuth.....

Comment: Why don't you pass the OAuth credentials then? Create them once, store them and then re-use them (okay that's not what Oauth was made for, but it works and is commonly exploited that way).

Comment: But this means from time to time the site over needs to create the token again....not (Sorry i'm absolutely new to OAuth)?